# StyleSheet.parseCSS converts style-names to lowercase in AIR

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am loading css file in Flex 3 AIR application. While reading the style name, I am lowercase version of it (i.e, `.NewFontStyle` is converted to `.newfontstyle`)

how to get name as mentioned in css file.

my code:

```
private  var prefsCSS:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

private function ReadStylesCSS():void
{
    fileStream.open(appStorageDirFile,FileMode.READ);
    prefsCSS.parseCSS(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable));
    fileStream.close();
}
```

I get my style names in prefsCSS.styleNames by looping through it.

```
for each (var item:String in prefsCSS.styleNames)
{                
    var stylename:String=item;
}
```

by this iam getting all styleNames in lower case only.. i need to get the name as mentioned in css file

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was checking if the file contained lower case style-names to begin with - since you've already verified that, my post is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Then how to handle this problem Amarghosh ? 
Is any other way to get the styleName ?

Comment: fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable) 

is returning in Right case but while parseCSS only iam getting this problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this behavior. The class [flash.text.StyleSheet](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) is not meant for parsing Flex CSS. It is used with TextField HTML where selectors should be all lowercase.

Comment: hi joshtynjala, Then there is no other way to get the styleName in the right case in Flex3 Air application.

Comment: If I were you, I would write my own CSS parser. Alternatively, you might use the recommended compiled CSS SWFs to load styles at runtime.